# Python Package for Categorizing Keywords

Tags: python, keyword

I am looking for a python package for categorizing keywords. I.e. I want to input Baseball and get "Sports and Outdoors". Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not using simple dictionaries and lists? `cat = {}`
`cat['Baseball'] = ['Sports', 'Outdoors']`
What do you need more?

Comment: Please add more detail to this question. What is your application area? What have you tried?

Comment: Were you able to find something like that? I'm trying to avoid training or building my own corpus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is probably the natural language toolkit.In particular ntlk.corpus.wordnet

But you will probably want to read up on some theory so spend some time with the book.

http://www.nltk.org/book

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any python library that categorizes keywords, but here is a simple hack/workaround to make your life easy. As @gecco commented, you should use a mapping between words and categories. To avoid hardcoding all of them, use an API like [this](http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/entity/) to fill such a dictionary.